# C# multiple background workers accessing an object

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a list of strings, containing about 20000 string each 1000 chars long. I want to replace all these strings with a reversed version of the same string in the same position using multiple background workers.

Heres what I'm doing so far:

Set up background workers (8 because computer has 8 cores)

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkComplete;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

The problem I am having is that I don't know what to put in the doWork function.

Should the dowork function keep looping like this:

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   while(list.count > 0)
   {
      reverse and add to list
   }         
}
```

Or should the doWork function only do the reversing and then pass the reversed string to the WorkComplete function?

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       reverse string
       r.result = reversed string 
    }
```

Comment: As an alternative to the background worker have you looked at the `Task Parallel Library`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: How do you want to keep track of which list items have been processed by other backgroundworker instances?

Comment: That's not really what a background worker (BGW) is designed to do.  You normally on have one BGW and it doesn't use shared data (other than in the progress and complete events).  If you want multiple things processing data at the same time, I'd suggest using the TPL and spin up a Task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd just like to suggest an alternative approach to this.

Rather than creating a number of BackgroundWorkers, you could just create one and inside its DoWork() you can use [`Parallel.ForEach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835497.aspx) to reverse the strings.

That way, it will handle the number of threads optimally for you.

You would still need to use a BackgroundWorker to avoid locking the UI thread.

Here's a compilable example running in a Console app:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] data = Enumerable.Range(10000, 100).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();

            Parallel.ForEach(data, (item, state, index) => data[index] = Reverse(item));

            foreach (var s in data)
                Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        public static string Reverse(string s)
        {
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you are using .Net 4.5 you can avoid using a BackgroundWorker completely by using the new `await/async` feature.

For example, create a default Windows Forms application and drop onto it a Label called `label1` and a button called `button1`. Then change the Form1.cs file to:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            data = Enumerable.Range(10000, 1000000).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
        }

        async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Reversing strings...";
            await doWork();
            label1.Text = "Reversed strings.";
        }

        Task doWork()
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach(data, (item, state, index) => data[index] = reverse(item)));
        }

        static string reverse(string s)
        {
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }

        readonly string[] data;
    }
}
```

When you click the button, the UI will remain responsive while the strings are reversed.

Comment: @686 I expect you might have to do a bit of reading of the documentation to see just how this works...

Comment: Cool this seems to be a very good solution. Sorry i cant up vote because i don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 2):

Is it crucial for you to use BackgroundWorker? Using TPL is very simple:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

Parallel.For(0, strings.Length, i=> strings[i] = reversed string);
```

TPL will balance the load for you( by default, it uses the available number of your CPU cores), and this also will work well on other machine, with different amount of cores.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Its not crucial for me to use the background worker. I just want the task to be completed as fast as possible. Ill give it a try